# Ionic 2 - Speech Recognition

Tags: ionic2, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

is there a way to use speech recognition in an Iionic 2 Project? All I came across are possibilities for Ionic 1 like in this post [Speech recognition using ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266264/speech-recognition-using-ionic-framework) . Ionic 2 already provides a native API for Text to Speech http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/texttospeech/ but I would need it the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Better question to ask yourself is, is there a `cordova` plugin for the thing I want?

And yes there are cordova plugins available.

https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin
https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer

Just instead of using `cordova plugin add .....` use `ionic plugin add ......` (will immediately update platforms).

Comment: Thanks, I came across this, too. But after I installed the plugin how do you reference this in yout ts/js?
import { SpeechRecognition } from 'plugins/cordova-plugin-speechrecognizer'; 
and then SpeechRecognition.speechrecognizer.startRecognize for example gives me "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "plugins/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition"

Comment: depends, the `SpeechRecognizer` can be used immediately like `SpeechRecognizer.startRecognize(success, error, maxMatches, promptString, language);` (see their docs) and the `SpeechRecognitionPlugin` I believe can be called by `new SpeechRecognition();`

Comment: ok so let´s stay with poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer plugin. Simply calling "SpeechRecognizer.startRecognize(success, error, maxMatches, promptString, language);" doesn´t work, it gives "Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'SpeechRecognizer'." I can hardly imagine that you don´t need to import sth...

Comment: can you try `import { SpeechRecognizer } from 'ionic-native';` ? That's at least the module where f.e. the Camera plugin are stored

Comment: ionic native doesn´t export any module named SpeechRecognizer. Wouldn´t we need to reference the plugin we just added in /plugins/cordova-plugin-speechrecognizer ? But I can´t make it work...

Comment: @Kniggos well you wont have to do it manually if you run the `ionic plugin add ...` command

Comment: I did it with the command, it added a new folder in the /plugins but I can´t just simply call "new SpeechRecognizer()" nor SpeechRecognizer.startRecognize(...) f.e.

Comment: @Kniggos, if you are still facing difficulty on using cordova plugin in your application, follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696420/how-to-use-a-plugin-without-using-ionic-native/38702473#38702473. Use your speechRecognizer plugin similar to it

Comment: @AishApp, so in my case it is "<clobbers target="plugins.speechrecognizer" /> ". When I use "declare var plugins: any;" and then call "plugins.speechrecognizer.my_method();" it says plugins is not defined. I´m not sure tho, if plugins is the base class as you mentioned in your post, but using "declare var speechrecognizer: any;" gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Cordova plugin for speech recognition [cordova-plugin-tts](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts) 
Since Ionic 2 uses TypeScript ,all you need is a way to use the plugin with TypeScript .The Github repo includes an example on how to do that

```
declare module TTS {
    interface IOptions {
        /** text to speak */
        text: string;
        /** a string like 'en-US', 'zh-CN', etc */
        locale?: string;
        /** speed rate, 0 ~ 1 */
        rate?: number;
    }

    function speak(options: IOptions, onfulfilled: () => void, onrejected: (reason) => void): void;
    function speak(text: string, onfulfilled: () => void, onrejected: (reason) => void): void;
}
```